# Transparent background render taking ages

Tags: rendering, animation

I am rendering a animation, I originally had a white background but that was taking forever, so I turned on transparent background.

The issue still persists, Blender wants to render the scene, each portion of the render fly's through, but 1 full transparent frame takes 25 seconds.[image: Time]

Is there a way I can tell blender to not care about transparent portions.

[image: Animation]

[image: More into the animation]

[image: Last Frame]
The animation is a phone coming up and rotating.
[image: Animation]

Comment: Hello :). Simply enable Adaptive sampling. Transparent areas are then rendered with 1 sample only.

Comment: @Emir That forum is very helpful thanks

Comment: @JachymMichal ah thanks ^^ didnt see that.